# When to use ** (double star) in glob syntax within JAVA

Tags: java, path, nio, glob, matcher

Directly from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html#glob) Java Oracle tutorial:

> Two asterisks, **, works like * but crosses directory boundaries. This
>   syntax is generally used for matching complete paths.

Could anybody do a real example out of it?
What do they mean with "crosses directory boundary"?
Crossing the directory boundary, I imagine something like checking the file from root to `getNameCount()-1`.
Again a real example explaining the difference between * and ** in *practice* would be great.

Comment: It means it will recursively go through all sub-directories, where * will only grab files from the current directory, ignoring sub-directories

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The javadoc for [`FileSystem#getPathMatcher()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher(java.lang.String)) has some pretty good examples and explanations

```
*.java Matches a path that represents a file name ending in .java 
*.*    Matches file names containing a dot 

*.{java,class}  Matches file names ending with .java or .class 
foo.?           Matches file names starting with foo. and a single character extension 
/home/*/*       Matches /home/gus/data on UNIX platforms 
/home/**        Matches /home/gus and /home/gus/data on UNIX platforms 
C:\\*           Matches C:\foo and C:\bar on the Windows platform (note that the backslash is escaped; as a string literal in the Java Language the pattern would be "C:\\\\*")
```

So `/home/**` would match `/home/gus/data`, but `/home/*` wouldn't.

`/home/*` is saying every file directly in the `/home` directory.

`/home/**` is saying every file in any directory inside `/home`.

---

Example of `*` vs `**`. Assuming your current working directory is `/Users/username/workspace/myproject`, then the following will only match the `./myproject` file (directory).

```
PathMatcher pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:/Users/username/workspace/*");
Files.walk(Paths.get(".")).forEach((path) -> {
    path = path.toAbsolutePath().normalize();
    System.out.print("Path: " + path + " ");
    if (pathMatcher.matches(path)) {
        System.out.print("matched");
    }
    System.out.println();
});
```

If you use `**`, it will match all folders and files within that directory.

Answer (score 30):

Double asterisk (`**`) matches zero or more characters across multiple nested directories. I will explain the double asterisk as well as other wildcards that are useful step by step with examples after explaining the main concept.

---

### Globbing

A *glob* is a string literal and/or wildcard characters used to match file paths. Locating files on a filesystem using one or more globs is called globbing. The globbing is not just limited to Java. It's also used for matching files in various configuration files, such as listing ignored files and directories in `.gitignore` in Git, selecting files and folders in Unix operating system, e.g `ls **/*.java` etc.

Following are some of the most important parts of globbing. Double asterisk(`**`) is one of them:

---

### Separator and Segments (`/`)

In Globbing, the forward slash character (`/`) always acts as the *separator*, no matter what operating system is being used. A *segment* is everything that comes between the two separators.

Example: `tests/HelloWorld.java`

Here, `tests` and `HelloWorld.java` are the segments and `/` is the separator.

---

### Single Asterisk (`*`)

Single Asterisk (*) matches zero or more characters within *one* segment. It is used for globbing the files within one directory.

Example: `*.java`

This glob will match files such as `HelloWorld.java` but not files like `tests/HelloWorld.java` or `tests/ui/HelloWorld.java`.

---

### Double Asterisk (`**`)

Double Asterisk (`**`) matches zero or more characters across *multiple* segments. It is used for globbing files that are in nested directories.

Example: `tests/**/*.java`

Here, the file selecting will be restricted to the `tests` directory. The glob will match the files such as `tests/HelloWorld.java`, `tests/ui/HelloWorld.java`, `tests/ui/feature1/HelloWorld.java`.

---

### Question Mark(`?`)

Question mark(`?`) matches a single character within one segment. It can be used for matching the files or folders that differ in name by just one character.

Example: `tests/?at.java`

This will match files such as `tests/cat.java`, `test/Cat.java`, `test/bat.java` etc.

---

### Square Brackets (`[abc]`)

Square Brackets (`[...]`) matches a single character given in the square brackets.

Example: `tests/[CB]at.java`

This glob will match files like `tests/Cat.java` or `tests/Bat.java`

---

### Square Brackets Range (`[a-z]`)

Square Brackets Range (`[a-z]`), matches one character given in the range.

Example: `tests/feature[1-9]/HelloWorld.java`

This glob will match files like `tests/feature1/HelloWorld.java`, `test/feature2/HelloWorld.java` and so on... upto `9`.

---

### Negation (`!`)

Negation (`!`) is used for excluding some files.

Example: `tests/[!C]at.java`

This will exclude the file `tests/Cat.java` and will match files like `tests/Bat.java`, `tests/bat.java`, `tests/cat.java`.

---

That's it! Hope that helps.

Comment: One thing I was mistaken on was I was actually using an older version of bash that doesn't support Globstar.