# What's the meaning of **/ in the beginning of **/.idea in my '.gitignore'

Tags: git

my .gitignore file

```
**/target/
**/.settings/
**/.classpath
**/.project
**/.idea/
**/*.iml
**/*.log
```

I dont know the meaning of the '**/' at the begining

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722471/when-to-use-double-star-in-glob-syntax-within-java

Comment: @ScaryWombat the question is about syntax of `gitignore`, not Java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The double asterisk  (`**`) is well [documented](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format):

> Two consecutive asterisks ("`**`") in patterns matched against full
>   pathname may have special meaning:
>
> - A leading "`**`" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For
>     example, "`**/foo`" matches file or directory "`foo`" anywhere, the same
>     as pattern "`foo`". "`**/foo/bar`" matches file or directory "`bar`"
>     anywhere that is directly under directory "`foo`".
> - A trailing "`/**`" matches everything inside. For example, "`abc/**`"
>     matches all files inside directory "`abc`", relative to the location of
>     the `.gitignore` file, with infinite depth.
> - A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash matches
>     zero or more directories. For example, "`a/**/b`" matches "`a/b`",
>     "`a/x/b`", "`a/x/y/b`" and so on.
> - Other consecutive asterisks are considered invalid.

Your case matches the first one, so this line: `**/.idea/` means: ignore `.idea` directory in any directory within the repository. So it would match `/.idea/`, `/foo/.idea/`, `/foo/bar/.idea/` etc.