# What does this wildcard mean?

Tags: css, json, gruntjs, wildcard

I have a grunt file which has several commands. One part was written by a colleague who's left, but we can't find an explanation what it means exactly.

It does what it should do, but knowing what is exactly, is something we don't :)

This is the code:

```
dist: {
    files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= config.tmp %>/styles/',
        src: '{,**/}*.css',
        dest: '<%= config.tmp %>/styles/'
    }]
}
```

The part we're not sure is `{,**/}` on line 5.

Comment: I think it means either in the current directory, or the parent directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{,**/}*.css` curly braces inside that pattern represent the feature known as Brace expansion. Internally [grunt is using Minimatch](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) library which supports that feature. List of comma separated patterns inside them will be expanded first into two patterns `*.css` and `**/*.css` in your case. You can test your pattern using [globster.xyz](https://globster.xyz/?q=%7B%2C**%2F%7D*.js&f=%2Fmyapp%2Freadme.md%2C%2Fmyapp%2Fconfig%2Fstaging.js%2C%2Fmyapp%2Fconfig%2Fproduction.js%2C%2Fmyapp%2Fsrc%2Fservices%2Futils.js%2C%2Fmyapp%2Fsrc%2Fservices%2Ftimezone.ts%2C%2Fmyapp%2Fsrc%2Fcontrollers%2Fhealth.js%2C%2Fmyapp%2Fsrc%2Fcontrollers%2Fuser.module.ts%2C%2Fmyapp%2Fassets%2Flogo.png%2C%2Fmyapp%2Fassets%2Flogo_small.png%2C%2Fmyapp%2Fassets%2Ffavicon.ico)

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns):

> `{}` allows for a comma-separated list of "or" expressions

Thus,

> ```
> '{,**/}*.css',
> ```

will match `*.css` and `**/*.css`.

The first pattern inside the brace is *redundant*, since the second one should already match .css files in the current/root directory.

Comment: I agree...That I got from the docs...but the comma is puzzling us, since it's normally used to separate something, but not here.

Answer (score 0):

> A great answer by [sotirios-delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis):
>
> [When to use ** (double star) in glob syntax within JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722471/when-to-use-double-star-in-glob-syntax-within-java)

The short story is that if you use one star than nested paths will ignored:

/a/a/a.css - ignored

The comma inside the curly braces it is what it is so files/directories with comma inside will not ignored:

dsadsad,dasdsadas/a.css