# Gradle sourceSets resource

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to use * as generic folder but it doesn't work.
I have the following config:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    resources { srcDirs = ['app/main/*/resources'] }
  }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `**` instead of `*`, the single asterisk is used for globbing files within a single directory, the double is for nested directories. Note that if you have multiple directories called `resources` nested inside `app/main/`, this will find all of them.

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    resources { srcDirs = ['app/main/**/resources'] }
  }
}
```

[See second answer on this question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722471/when-to-use-double-star-in-glob-syntax-within-java)