# Github CODEOWNERS Syntax - Name included in directory?

Tags: github, gitignore, github-codeowners

In Github CODEOWNERS, I want to set a rule for **"directories that contains the word `<TEAM_NAME>`"**.

I assume it'd be something like this if possible: `src/**<TEAM_NAME>**/**`

---

For example, if I have such directory structure:

```
src/
  index.js
  features/
    auth/
    sales-feature1/
    sales-feature2/
    marketing-feature1/
    marketing-feature2/
    marketing-feature3/
  utils/
    sales-util1/
    sales-util2/
```

I want to set CODEOWNERS like:

```
src/**sales**/**   @github-sales-team
```

Which will apply to the below files

```
src/features/sales-feature1/**
src/features/sales-feature2/**
src/utils/sales-util1/**
src/utils/sales-util2/*
```

**Question**: What to set for `src/**sales**/**` to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems CODEOWNERS follows .gitigonore rule with some exceptions

And the following link from other is helpful

[When to use ** (double star) in glob syntax within JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722471/when-to-use-double-star-in-glob-syntax-within-java)

[gitignore rule](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format)

[exception rule in CODEOWNERS file](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners#syntax-exceptions)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31079926)